# Can I disable to reset selections when click background in forge viewer?

Tags: autodesk-forge

In my product, I do not want selections to be reset under certain conditions.

But selections must be able to add.

So, I want to cancel selection change with "before selection change event".

please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I'm not aware of any way the viewer would allow you to do this *officially*. What can be configured is - you can lock certain dbIDs to make them unselectable - but I'm guessing that wouldn't really help in your particular case.

With that said, you could possibly modify the selection behavior by modifying the `viewer.impl.selector` object which basically encapsulates all the selection logic (look for the `Selector` class in https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/viewer3D.js). But that would be a brittle hack, as anything under `viewer.impl` is considered internal implementation and as such shouldn't be relied upon.

Comment: Thanks for the great tips! I disabled the click event by modifying the `viewer.clickHandler.clickConfig.click.offObject` and `viewer.toolController.handleDoubleClick` objects.